# Como inserir linhas dinâmica em tabela HTML, e ja definir de ante-mão uma classe

Tags: javascript, table, dom, dinâmico, append

Tenho uma tabela HTML e estou criando suas linhas de modo dinâmico fazendo uso `appendChild()`, só não estou conseguindo definir `className` dinamicamente nessas linhas, na terceira coluna - "VALOR".

Vide como esta:

```js
        var doc = document;

        function inserirLinha(id) {
            var newRow = doc.createElement('tr');
            newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = 'ID';
            newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'NOME';
            newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = 'VALOR';
            doc.getElementById(id).appendChild(newRow);
            return false;
        }
```

```html
    <form onsubmit="return inserirLinha('minhaTabela')">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <tbody id="minhaTabela"></tbody>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta atribuir o **insertCell** numa variável e depois definir o nome da classe que você quer usando a propriedade **className**

```js
var opt = document;

function inserirLinha(id) {
  var newRow = opt.createElement('tr');
  newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = 'ID';
  newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'NOME';
  colunaValor = newRow.insertCell(2);
  colunaValor.innerHTML = 'VALOR';
  colunaValor.className = 'teste';
  opt.getElementById(id).appendChild(newRow);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return inserirLinha('minhaTabela')">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <tbody id="minhaTabela"></tbody>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" name="submit">
</form>
```